# Why 'shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale' is related to Activity?

Tags: android, android-permissions

As long as permissions are part of an Application at all, I wonder why it's needed to use `Activity` for `shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale`, instead of `Context` or `Application`?

May it return different results being called on different activities?

Comment: "May it return different results being called on different activities?" -- no. "why it's needed to use Activity for shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale, instead of Context or Application?" -- AFAIK, Google believes that showing such rationale is the role of the UI, so it put that method on `Activity`.

Comment: "showing such rationale is the role of the UI" - this is obvious, if we speak about _showing_. But In my case it is UI-independed logic.

Comment: Then do not call `shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale()`. The second word of that method name is "show", and so if you are not interesting in showing things, that method is of little use to you.

Comment: Unfortunately calling `shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale()` is the only way to get know if user had checked "never show again"